# Method of Moments of Uniform Distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution, method-of-moments

Let $x_1=2, x_2 = 1, x_3 = \sqrt5, x_4 = \sqrt2$ be the observed values of a random sample of size 4 from a uniform distribution $U(-\theta, \theta)$ where $\theta>0$. Then the method of moments estimate of $\theta$ is?

a) 1
b) 2
c) 3
d) 4

The way I approached this question is:
The first method of moment is $\bar{X}$ = $\sum X_i/n$ = ($2+1+\sqrt5+\sqrt2)/4 = 1.66$.
Expected value of $U(-\theta, \theta)$ = ($-\theta+\theta)/2 = 0$. I am unable to interpret further.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Since the sample mean isn't helping you, try working with the sample variance (second central moment) and equating it to the population variance.  Note: when constructing the sample variance, you know the true mean is zero, so you should use that instead of the sample mean, and divide by $n (=4)$ instead of $n-1$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Please tag this question as self-study, or let us know if it is homework.

Answer (score 6):

The mean of this distribution is always zero so it does not depend on the parameter $\theta$.  For that reason, if you were using MOM estimation you could use the second raw moment, which is:

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \frac{\theta^2}{3}.$$

Equating this to the sample moment $R_n^2 \equiv \tfrac{1}{n} \sum x_i^2$ gives the MOM estimator:

$$\hat{\theta}_n = \sqrt{3} \cdot R_n.$$

With your particular data $\mathbf{x}_4 = (2,1,\sqrt{5},\sqrt{2})$ you have $R_4^2 = 3$ so you get the estimated parameter value $\hat{\theta}_4 = \sqrt{3} \cdot R_4 = \sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt{3} = 3$.

---

**An alternative method:** Pursuing the suggestion in the comment from [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/) below, another option would be to form the MOM for $|X| \sim \text{U}[0, \theta)$.  In this case we have the first raw moment (the mean):

$$\mathbb{E}(|X|) = \frac{\theta}{2}.$$

Equating this to the sample moment $A_n \equiv \tfrac{1}{n} \sum |x_i|$ gives the MOM estimator:

$$\hat{\theta}_n = 2 \cdot A_n.$$

With your data you have $A_4 = \tfrac{1}{4} (3+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{2}) \approx 1.66257$ so you get the estimated parameter value $\hat{\theta}_4 \approx 3.32514$.  This is similar to the result for the previous MOM estimate.

Comment: (+1) Of interest -- as suggested by the positivity of the data -- would be to find the MoM estimator for $|X|,$ which has a Uniform$[0,\theta]$ distribution.

Comment: @whuber: Added.